# Error: "Composer cannot be run safely on non-cli sapis with register_argc_argv=On"

Tags: php, composer-php

I tried to install a laravel project on my hosting and I need to install composer. If I write `php composer.phar` I get the message:

> Composer cannot be run safely on non-cli sapis with register_argc_argv=On

I don't have access to the PHP configuration files because it seems to be shared hosting.

Comment: You'll need to better describe the what you're doing, including the commands you're running and how you're attempting to invoke them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I check if composer is installed with the command in SSH. Every time I use "composer" I get the above message.

Comment: You shouldn't be running `install` on production. You need to run the `install` commands locally (or on a "build" machine), and upload the resulting artifact to your server.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Here's the problem, which needs to be corrected, I'm trying to move a project from localhost to hosting (probably shared). I'm issuing installation commands in SSH, which I just - receive back with such above error. 

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, the solution is **not** to run `composer install` on the server. Build the project locally (with `--no-dev`), and upload the resulting files.

Comment: Actually logical. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Wholehearted agreement with @Yivi's comments, Composer does not need to run in production and ideally should not. When Composer runs as part of build/deploy it will pull in all dependencies and generate relevant autoloader config that will then run without any actual dependency on the Composer binary/phar. Just deploy the app including the `vendor/` dir and it should work as expected.

But specifically with regard to the error that you're getting it seems like the machine may not have a php-cli instance installed. Instead it's possible you're invoking a php-cgi binary which I believe can technically still function in a CLI context, though it's not ideal.

To check the SAPI in use you can run:

```
php -r 'var_dump(php_sapi_name());'
```

and to get an idea which binary is being invoked on the server run:

```
which php; file $(which php)
```

Which should give you the full path to `php` and tell you if it an actual binary, or a symlink to something else like `php-cgi`.

If it turns out that you don't have a php-cli installed then you can install a relevant package for that via your distro's package manager *if necessary*. If you're only ever going to be running PHP via a web context, then this is unnecessary and can be confusing as CLI/CGI instances can and do frequently use different config files and/or be different versions of PHP entirely.